# I want a script on movement unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I just started making game for the first time in my life on unity and I followed many tutorials and made my character move but it wont jump after 6 tutorials my character now started rotation whenever i press a button so I deleted that project and now I am making a new project so kindly can i get a movement script for my game which make my character move and specially jump it would help a lot.

Comment: Can you show us what you tried until now?

Answer (score 3):

I know you probably just want someone to write or copy the code for you, but as someone who was stuck in the cycle of watching tutorials and then forgetting everything, the best advice I can give you is to actually start learning the basics of C# and Unity. They have a pretty good course for beginners on their free learning Platform [here](https://learn.unity.com). Following Tutorials or Copying all the code will not teach you anything and demotivate you in the long run.

Comment: While not really an answer as this question is off topic for stackoverflow. I 100% agree.  If following tutorials and you havent learnt or understood.  Then either it was a terrible tutorial or you are not engaging with it. Never just blindly follow. Look up methods and google to read more.

Comment: Yep sry for the Offtopic answer but I feel like this is the most important thing to learn if one wants to stay motivated.

Comment: Na you're good, sure, it arguably should have been flagged as not an answer etc, but i agree too much  and want to preserve this. Far too many come out of tutorials having typed what they were told but clearly took in absolutely nothing of why.  such as Ive seen code resembling "x++; but my thing only moves to the right, how do i make it move left" ?? theres just no connection no understanding and its painful for people trying to help and discouraging for the person as they dont seem to know anything and no one want wants to basically dictate to them each time